# What's the idea behind using try with `catch { throw }`?

Tags: powershell-2.0

In PowerShell v2.0 if I do this:

```
gc function:\mkdir
```

I get some code which contains this:

```
try {
    $steppablePipeline.End()
} catch {
    throw
}
```

What's the idea of `try/catch/throw` here?

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe it makes it look like the exception was thrown from the `throw` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a proxy function, a function that is a wrapper around another (or a cmdlet), with the inbuilt tools (see [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/03/01/proxy-functions-spice-up-your-powershell-core-cmdlets.aspx) for an example) the generated code includes that code. It is intended to allow easy modification, but if the generated code is sufficient then why change it?

Comment: So `mkdir` is just a proxy function to `New-Item` generated with the tools mentioned in the article?

Comment: @KonstantinSpirin It certainly appears to be the case. Minimally edited to remove the `-Type` parameter and change it to a fixed value.